# force table name before field in select

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CCONTACT_FK = T2 .CCONTACT_PK
```

Both tables have a date_createField, so when I use select *, date_createField is returned twice. I could solve this by changing my select to:

```
SELECT T1.date_createField, T2.date_createField
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CCONTACT_FK = T2 .CCONTACT_PK
```

But is it possible to not specify the specifik fields (keep select *), and force the table name in front of the property?

I'm having this problem because I'm joining 2 tables with a lot of columns and some columns have the same name. I would like to use select * and still have a distinction between columns present in both tables. Is this possible?

Comment: `select * ` should be avoided in production code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible you need to specify the column names or accept all columns.  If this is a query you will execute often make a view which can be reused.

Comment: So when you write a query whithout specifying the columns and the query returns a result with 2 identical column names, there is no way to distinct those 2? I guess I'll have no option then by summing up all columns I need

Comment: @Vincent There is now way to use `select *` and not return all columns.

Comment: SELECT T1.*, T2.*
    FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CCONTACT_FK = T2 .CCONTACT_PK

Comment: Ye, but maybe you could change the way it names the returned columns.

Comment: @Mumumar this returns the same result as a regular select *

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CCONTACT_FK = T2 .CCONTACT_PK
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid listing out the columns for the tables.  They would need to specify each column in the second table.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Jep that's what I'm looking for